# Is it Possible to Select/Animate an Object in CSS while Hovering over another Different Object?

Tags: html, css, animation

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<div id="object1">1</div>
<div id="object2">2</div>
```

Is it possible that I set the properties of lets say object 2 while hovering over object 1? I know that there are **General Sibling Selectors** for selecting siblings of an object or in this example you could use the **Adjacent Sibling Selector(+)** like this:

```css
#obj1 {
    color: blue;
}
#obj2 {
    color: orange;
}

#obj1:hover + #obj2 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>   
    <div id="obj1">Hover over to change color</div>
    <div id="obj2">If you hover over the text above this should get red</div>
</body>
```

But this is only possible when the "object2 div" is right after the "object1 div". What if both div tags were in completely different positions? Is there a way to do that or isn't it possible?

Comment: `~` is other sibling selector.

Comment: It is only possible if there is a sibling relation between your trigger element, and the target element - with trigger coming before target. You can "reach into" the target element, to format descendant elements further down in there, based on that the trigger element got hovered. But that's about it, other completely arbitrary constellations won't work.

Comment: u need js, it makes things ez

Comment: Okay so basically it isn't possible in plain CSS. Thanks guys :)